# Filter strong and b from content through views

Tags: views

I'm use CKeditor, which inserts b and strong tags for bold text, and sometimes when Drupal is showing teasers, only the opening tag is included. Resulting in the bold type face cascading down and being applied to all the text below it. Is there any way to filter out particular html tags(strong, b) from the teaser display in views?

EDIT: If one chooses to use fields, there is also the option in views to strip all html but leave particular tags, which is can accomplish the same thing but from the opposite direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using "show teasers option" for rows if yes switch to fields option.

Once you are using the fields add body field and add "Trim this field" then you could either click field may contain html, which will close the html tags before cut-off or you could pick strip html all together...

[image]

Comment: Thanks this definitely helps and it's what I'll use for now. Do you know of any way to strip individual tags by name? so not to allow "strong" to appear at all in the views output?

Comment: @A_funs The way i would do that is open theme information get the possible override name for theme files, and create a custom override in which i would do `str_replace(<strong>,'',$variable); str_replace(</strong>,'',$variable);`

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ahh also a good technique